# how to place an Alphabet bar on joomla category list

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, categories, joomla3.0

In joomla 3 I can load categories under one particular category order by alphabet.

I want to show a alphabet bar like below I have created and placed on editing

**layout/joomla/content/category-default.php**

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q ....

the catergories should show like

**A**

apple

Art

**B**

Breakfast

...

when we click on alphabet letter in bar it should go to particular area(ID) on list.

please tell anyone if you know how can I group and place a heading with ID to those category and where do I need to work on joomla files?

Comment: This would be better fit for http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tereško -This is not in any way associated with Magento

Comment: lol .. sorry .. had a brain-fart.

Comment: I found the answer and added below , Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternative layout on the categories view.  I would probably use a JLayout for the alphabet bar. 
THen in your foreach
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/components/com_content/views/categories/tmpl/default_items.php#L18

You'd have to check for a new letter and if it is there put the letter heading.

The only issue would be what if there is nothing under a letter.  Would you still be okay with having the link?  If not you'd probably need a plugin to run another query to gather the first letters of the results.

Comment: I found the page to edit, it is not components/com_content/views/categories/tmpl/default_items.php#L18

Comment: I found the page to edit, it is not categories/tmpl/default_items.php it is on category/default_child.php. only one letter is not available that is 'X' letter in categories. how can i sort it out and I'm not familiar on joomla mvc at all.

Comment: I found the answer and added below , Thank you very much Elin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question, I have edited the page on 
components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/default_children.php

added the alphabetic bar on before foreach with id

```
$lastletter = 0;

|<a href="#LetterA"> A </a>|<a href="#LetterB"> B </a>| <a href="#LetterC">C </a>| <a href="#LetterD">D</a> | <a href="#LetterE">E</a>
```

inside foreach enter the below code

```
$currentleter = substr($this->escape($child->title),0,1);  

if ($lastletter != $currentleter):
echo '<div id="Letter' . $currentleter .  '" class="letterheader">' . $currentleter . '</div>';
$lastletter = $currentleter;
endif;
```

**it is working nicely, Thank GOD and who ever helped me specially Elin**

Comment: Great, but don't edit the file since you may lose changes when updating. Instead you want to make a layout override. http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core